# How to allow custom ExceptionFilter to continue to call the designated Action Method during exceptions

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, filter

When my Exception Filter is called, I'd like the intended action within my controller to still be called. I had created the following IExceptionFilter:

```
    public class ArgumentExceptionFilter : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(System.ArgumentException))
            {
                //Some logic to create a default "SettingsRoot" parameter

                //This simply surpresses MVC from raising exception
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

and this filter is applied to this controller action method:

```
   [ArgumentExceptionFilter]
   public ActionResult MyActionMethod(SettingsRoot settings)
   {
     ActionResult actionResult = null;

     //Do stuff with settings

     return actionResult;
   }
```

I would like to have "MyActionMethod()" to be called regardless if we get an exception that triggers the ExceptionFilter. I also tried to use "RedirectToRouteResult()" approach but that didn't work. **Any suggestions?**

Comment: it _is_ being called, and the exception occurs somewhere inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Result property of the filterContext to redirect to your controller action with a default parameter.

```
    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception.GetType() == typeof(System.ArgumentException))
        {
            //This simply surpresses MVC from raising exception
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

            //Some logic to create a default "SettingsRoot" parameter
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary
            {
                { "controller", "Default" },
                { "action", "MyActionMethod" },
                { "settings", new SettingsRoot() }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Get an error stating the route doesn't exists for the "Default" contorller/route. My controller name is "MySettingsController" and if I replace the controller "Default" with "MySettings", execution doesn't go to my controller action method it just simply returns to the client/caller with HttpStatus 200 and empty content. What am I missing here?

Comment: By the way, this action method is accessed via 'PUT' while another action method having the same action name is used via a "GET" to update the Settings object, not sure if that matters or not.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible then, redirecting will always have to be to a view and not a post action. In that case you will have to validate and update the parameter before sending it to the controller and redirect to an error page from the exception filter.